# extract and delete files from one tar and add to another new one

Tags: linux, tar, bzip2

I have a `bzip2`ed tar file and a text file with a list of files. I want to extract the files listed in the text file from the tar, add them to a new tar, and then delete them from the first tar.

For example, if I have a tar file like this:

```
$ tar -tvf test.tar.bz2
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:30 one/test/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/a
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/b
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/a
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/b
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/c/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/c/a
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/c/b
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/d/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/d/a
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/d/b
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:34 one/test/e/
```

And a text file with a list of files like this:

```
$ cat files_to_extract
one/test/b
one/test/e/
one/test/c/b
one/test/c/d/a
```

After it is done, this is what the original tar file should look like:

```
$ tar -tvf test.tar.bz2
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:30 one/test/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/a
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/a
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/c/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/c/a
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/c/b
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/d/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/d/b
```

And what the new tar file should look like.

```
$ tar -tvf new.tar.bz2
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/b
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/b
drwxrwxrwx nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:34 one/test/e/
-rw-rw-rw- nacho/nacho       0 2018-11-16 23:25 one/test/c/d/a
```

Note, the order of the files is irrelevant.

Comment: What have you tried to do? This seems like something a basic python (or maybe even bash) script could do

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This page is intended for programming questions.

Comment: tried that and they said to come here

Comment: Okay, that's weird.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

Extract files from "files_to_extract" to stdout and pipe to another tar:

```
tar -xOjf test.tar.bz2 -T files_to_extract | tar -cjf new.tar.bz2 -T -
```

Unzip, delete from tar and bzip it again:

```
bunzip2 test.tar.bz2
tar -f test.tar --delete $(cat files_to_extract)
bzip2 test.tar
```

Uncommon options documentation:

- -O (https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-Standard-Output.html)
- -T (https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html#SEC108)